# XAMPP Retrieving URL via $_GET

Tags: php, xampp

I have setup XAMPP on my local machine.  I am starting to setup my MVC and noticed that the $_GET is returning my local directory structure all the way to the drive letter.  But I want to return the URL structure.

I have attempted to provide all possible relevant information.

**Environment**

- Windows 7 Professional SP1 64-bit
- [XAMPP 1.8.1](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

**hosts** [C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts]

```
127.0.0.1       www.getspark.com
```

**httpd.conf** [E:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf]

```
DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/home"

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /xampp/htdocs/home
    ServerName getspark
</VirtualHost>
<Directory "E:/xampp/htdocs/home/private">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory />
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

**Web Directory Structure** [E:\xampp\htdocs\home]

```
home
    index.php
    private
        controllers
    public
        graphics
            HTML5_Logo_512.png
```

**Home Page** [E:\xampp\htdocs\home\index.php | http://www.getspark.com/]

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
echo $url . '<br />';
?>
<img src="/public/graphics/HTML5_Logo_512.png" />
```

If I use the following URL:

```
http://www.getspark.com/foobar
```

I get this output:

```
E:/xampp/htdocs/home/foobar
```

As well as the image.

But I want this output:

```
foobar
```

All relative (and absolute) references work correctly (for images, php files, js files, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

It's considered better practice to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], which returns everything in the request  after the domain (as per apache/lighty, before rewrite) - "/foobar" in your case.